# Issue with RecyclerView data interchanges while scrolling

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

There is Scroll by loading **RecyclerView(Lazy loading)**. When an item quantity is incremented by adding the plus button to say 10. after loading the next set of items while scrolling, The item quantity(10) is reset to 1 and 10 will be displayed for another item.

In the same sequence, if the unit is changed(by the spinner) to another unit the corresponding image will be loaded but after scrolling the unit and image will change back to initial unit.

When the image of an item is clicked, a dialog will show the details of the selected item . Sometimes the image in the dialog is correct but image of the RecyclerView is incorrect, will take time to load or will not load.

```
public class ArticleRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "ArticleAdapter";
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;

    private Context context;
    private Dialog articleDescriptionDialog;
    private UOMOffersLIistViewAdapter uomOffersLIistViewAdapter;
    private List<ArticleDetails> articleDetailsList;
    private HomeActivityViewModel homeActivityViewModel;
    private ItemFilter itemFilter = new ItemFilter();
    private GetViewListener getViewListener;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener;
    private boolean isLoading = false, isMoreDataAvailable = true;
    /*
     * isLoading - to set the remote loading and complete status to fix back to back load more call
     * isMoreDataAvailable - to set whether more data from server available or not.
     * It will prevent useless load more request even after all the server data loaded
     * */

    public ArticleRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ArticleDetails> articleDetailsList
            , HomeActivityViewModel homeActivityViewModel, Fragment fragment) {

        this.context = context;
        this.articleDetailsList = articleDetailsList;
        this.homeActivityViewModel = homeActivityViewModel;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            return new ItemViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_article_layout, parent, false));
        } else {
            return new LoadHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_loading_layout, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        if (position >= getItemCount() - 1 && isMoreDataAvailable && !isLoading && loadMoreListener != null) {
           
            isLoading = true;
            loadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
        }

        if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            populateItemRows((ItemViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        }
        //No else part needed as load holder doesn't bind any data
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (articleDetailsList.get(position).isLoading()) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_LOADING;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articleDetailsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /* VIEW HOLDERS */
    static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView stockImageView, copyStockImageView;
        private TextView articleNameTextView, articleStockAmountTextView, articleOfferTextView, addCartTextView;
        private NumberPicker articleStockQuantityNumberPicker;
        private Spinner articleStockSpinner;
        private ImageButton offerInfoImageButton;
        private int selectedStockItemPosition, stockQuantity;
        private String articleStockQuantityString = "";
        private Integer stockId;
        private double stockAmount;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            stockImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stockImgv);
            copyStockImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.copyStockImgv);//for fly to cart animation
            articleNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.articleNameTxt);
            articleStockAmountTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_amount_txt);
            articleOfferTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer_txt);
            offerInfoImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.offerInfo_imgbtn);
            addCartTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addCart_txt);
            articleStockSpinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_spnr);
            articleStockQuantityNumberPicker = itemView.findViewById(R.id.qty_numberPicker);
            articleStockQuantityNumberPicker.setMin(1);
            articleStockQuantityNumberPicker.setUnit(1);
            // no limit.
            // viewHolder.quantityNumberPicker.setMax(15);
        }
    }

    static class LoadHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LoadHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public void setMoreDataAvailable(boolean moreDataAvailable) {
        isMoreDataAvailable = moreDataAvailable;
    }


    /**
     * notifyDataSetChanged is final method so we can't override it
     * call articleRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataChanged(); after update the list
     */
    public void notifyDataChanged() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        isLoading = false;
    }


    public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
        void onLoadMore();
    }

    public void setLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener) {
        this.loadMoreListener = loadMoreListener;
    }

    private void populateItemRows(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int itemPos) {

        int itemPosition = itemViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        try {
            itemViewHolder.copyStockImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error_logo);//initialize with error logo.
            itemViewHolder.stockImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error_logo);//initialize with error logo.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        itemViewHolder.articleNameTextView.setText(articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getArticleName());
        itemViewHolder.articleNameTextView.setSelected(true);//for marquee
        itemViewHolder.articleOfferTextView.setSelected(true);//for marquee
        itemViewHolder.articleStockAmountTextView.setSelected(true);//for marquee


        itemViewHolder.articleOfferTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);//for demo (now no offer and schemes).
        itemViewHolder.offerInfoImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);//for demo
        setStockSpinner(itemViewHolder, itemPosition);

      

        itemViewHolder.offerInfoImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //setUOMOffersDIalog(articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition));
            }
        });

        itemViewHolder.articleStockQuantityNumberPicker.setValueChangedListener(new ValueChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(int quantity, ActionEnum action) {

              
                itemViewHolder.articleStockQuantityString = Integer.valueOf(quantity).toString();
            }
        });

        itemViewHolder.addCartTextView.setOnClickListener(new SingleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                itemViewHolder.articleStockQuantityString = Integer.valueOf(itemViewHolder.articleStockQuantityNumberPicker.getValue()).toString();
                itemViewHolder.stockQuantity = Integer.valueOf(itemViewHolder.articleStockQuantityString);
                itemViewHolder.stockAmount = articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getStockDetailsList()
                        .get(itemViewHolder.articleStockSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getmRP();
                itemViewHolder.stockId = articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getStockDetailsList()
                        .get(itemViewHolder.articleStockSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getStockId();
                

                Double stockDiscountAmount = 0.0;
                //TODO: 26-Oct-19 discount hardcoded.

                if (itemViewHolder.stockQuantity > 0) {
                    addItemToCart(itemViewHolder, itemViewHolder.stockId, itemViewHolder.stockQuantity, itemViewHolder.stockAmount, stockDiscountAmount);
                } else {
                    //not using (used  for when user enter invalid quantity)
                    MDToast.makeText(context, FinalVariables.ToastMessages.VALID_QUANTITY
                            , MDToast.LENGTH_SHORT, MDToast.TYPE_WARNING).show();
                }
            }
        });


        itemViewHolder.stockImageView.setOnClickListener(new SingleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSingleClick(View v) {

                itemViewHolder.articleOfferTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                itemViewHolder.articleOfferTextView.setText( ""+ itemViewHolder.stockQuantity);

                DialogUtils.showArticleDescription(context, articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition)
                        , itemViewHolder.selectedStockItemPosition, new DialogButtonClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void positiveButtonClick() {
                        //do nothing.
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Here you apply the animation when the view is bound
        setAnimation(itemViewHolder.itemView, itemPosition);
    }

    private void setStockSpinner(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int itemPosition) {

        UOMSpinnerAdapter uomSpinnerAdapter = new UOMSpinnerAdapter(context, R.layout.spinner_uom_layout
                , StringUtils.makeUomStringArrayForSpinner(articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getStockDetailsList()));
        itemViewHolder.articleStockSpinner.setAdapter(uomSpinnerAdapter);

        // Setting OnItemClickListener to the Spinner
        itemViewHolder.articleStockSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                itemViewHolder.selectedStockItemPosition = position;

                itemViewHolder.articleStockAmountTextView.setText(StringUtils.addAED(StringUtils.round3(
                        +articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition)
                                .getStockDetailsList().get(position).getmRP())));

                //show image from link
                try {
                    if (!articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getStockDetailsList().
                            get(position).getStockImageDetailsList().isEmpty()) {

                        ImageUtils.setGlide(context, itemViewHolder.stockImageView
                                , articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getStockDetailsList().
                                        get(position).getStockImageDetailsList().get(0).getStockImage());
                        //same as stockImageView but used to animate fly to cart
                        ImageUtils.setGlide(context, itemViewHolder.copyStockImageView
                                , articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getStockDetailsList().
                                        get(position).getStockImageDetailsList().get(0).getStockImage());
                    } else {
                       
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                   
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                if (articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getStockDetailsList().size() > 0)
                    itemViewHolder.articleStockAmountTextView.setText(StringUtils.addAED(
                            StringUtils.round3(+articleDetailsList.get(itemPosition).getStockDetailsList().get(0).getmRP())));
                itemViewHolder.selectedStockItemPosition = itemViewHolder.articleStockSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            }
        });

    }

    private void addItemToCart(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, Integer stockId, Integer stockQuantity
            , Double stockAmount, Double stockDiscountAmount) {

        homeActivityViewModel.isItemAlreadyCarted(stockId
                , new RetrieveDataListner() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDone(Object object) {
                        boolean isItemAlreadyCarted = (boolean) object;
                        if (!isItemAlreadyCarted) {//item not in cart,add to cart.

                            CartedItems cartedItem = new CartedItems();
                            cartedItem.setStockId(stockId);
                            cartedItem.setStockQuantity(stockQuantity);
                            cartedItem.setStockAmount(stockAmount);
                            cartedItem.setTotalAmount(CalcUtils.calculateTotalAmount(stockQuantity, stockAmount));
                            cartedItem.setNetAmount(CalcUtils.calculateNetAmount(stockQuantity
                                    , stockAmount, stockDiscountAmount));

                            homeActivityViewModel.insertCartedItem(cartedItem
                                    , new InsertDbSuccessListner() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess() {
                                           
                                            //set view to call back method for fly to cart animation
                                            if (getViewListener != null){
                                                getViewListener.onGetView(itemViewHolder.copyStockImageView);
                                                
                                            }

                                            itemViewHolder.articleStockQuantityNumberPicker.setValue(1);//reset item quantity in ui.
                                            // TODO: 21-Mar-19 check fly to cart only in home activity or not
                                            if (context instanceof MainActivity) {
                                                MDToast.makeText(context, TextMessages.ITEM_ADDED
                                                        , MDToast.LENGTH_SHORT, MDToast.TYPE_SUCCESS).show();
                                            } else if (context instanceof HomeActivity) {
                                                try {
                                                    ((HomeActivity) context).setCartDetails();
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure() {
                                            
                                        }
                                    });

                        } else {//item already carted,asking to add new quantity to carted quantity.
                            DialogUtils.showConformAlertDialog1(context, TextMessages.ITEM_ALREADY_CARTED
                                    , TextMessages.ITEM_ALREADY_CARTED_WARNING
                                    , StringValues.NO, StringValues.YES, new DialogButtonClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void positiveButtonClick() {//adding new quantity to existing quantity.
                                            //set view to call back method for fly to cart animation
                                            if (getViewListener != null)
                                                getViewListener.onGetView(itemViewHolder.copyStockImageView);
                                           
                                            homeActivityViewModel.updateCartedItemWithExistingValues(stockId, stockQuantity
                                                    , CalcUtils.calculateTotalAmount(stockQuantity, stockAmount),
                                                    CalcUtils.calculateNetAmount(stockQuantity, stockAmount, stockDiscountAmount)
                                                    , null);
                                            itemViewHolder.articleStockQuantityNumberPicker.setValue(1);//reset item quantity in ui.

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void negativeButtonClick() {
                                           
                                        }

                                    });
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Here is the key method to apply the animation
     */
    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.fall_down);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }


    /**
     * register listener for get article image(copyStockImageView)
     * for fly to cart animation.
     * the view get back to the call back(categorizedArticleFragment)).
     *
     * @param getViewListener
     */
    public void setGetViewListener(GetViewListener getViewListener) {
        this.getViewListener = getViewListener;
        
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return itemFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<ArticleDetails> list = articleDetailsList;

            int count = list.size();
            final List<ArticleDetails> nlist = new ArrayList<ArticleDetails>(count);

            ArticleDetails filterableString;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.getArticleName().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            articleDetailsList = (ArrayList<ArticleDetails>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Fragments onCreate

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup viewGroup,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        parentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_article, viewGroup, false);
        homeActivityViewModel = getViewModel();
        articleRecyclerView = parentView.findViewById(R.id.subcategory_rcylv);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();  
        Integer offset = bundle.getInt(TagNames.OFFSET, 0);
        Integer numberOfRows = bundle.getInt(TagNames.NUMBER_OF_ROWS,  FinalVariables.GETTING_DATA_COUNT_FROM_API);
        filterTypeId = bundle.getInt(TagNames.FILTER_TYPE_ID, FilterTypes.SUGGESTED);
        String filterText = bundle.getString(TagNames.FILTER_TEXT, "");
        Integer categoryId = bundle.getInt(TagNames.CATEGORY_ID, 0);
        initArticleRecyclerViewAdapter(articleDetailsList, filterText, categoryId, offset, numberOfRows);
        return parentView;
    }
```

Initializing Adapter

```
 private void initArticleRecyclerViewAdapter(List<ArticleDetails> articleDetailsList
            , String filterText, Integer categoryId, int offset, int numberOfRows) {

        articleRecyclerViewAdapter = new ArticleRecyclerViewAdapter(context, this.articleDetailsList, homeActivityViewModel, this);
        articleRecyclerViewAdapter.setLoadMoreListener(new ArticleRecyclerViewAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {

                articleRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int index = ArticleFragment.this.articleDetailsList.size();
                        loadMore(filterText, categoryId, index, numberOfRows);
                        Log.e(TAG, "scrolling,index: " + index);
                    }
                });
                //Calling loadMore function in Runnable to fix the
                // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling error
            }
        });

        articleRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        articleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 3));
        articleRecyclerView.setAdapter(articleRecyclerViewAdapter);    
      load(filterText, categoryId, offset, numberOfRows);
    }
```

Loading data

```
private void loadMore(String filterText, Integer categoryId, int offset, int numberOfRows) {

        //add loading progress view
        articleDetailsList.add(new ArticleDetails(true));
        articleRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInserted(articleDetailsList.size() - 1);

        Integer storeId = FileUtils.getPreferenceInt(context
                , Preferences.CUSTOMER_PREFERENCE, TagNames.STORE_ID);
        Integer distributionChannelId = FileUtils.getPreferenceInt(context
                , Preferences.CUSTOMER_PREFERENCE, TagNames.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_ID);
       
        homeActivityViewModel.getAllStockItemByCustomer(
                DeviceUtils.getCredential(context, ServiceNames.GET_ALL_STOCK_ITEM_BY_CUSTOMER)
                , storeId, distributionChannelId, filterTypeId, filterText, categoryId, offset, numberOfRows
                , new ApiCallbackListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object object) {
                      
                        try {
                            if (object != null) {
                                if (object instanceof GetAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn) {
                                    //otp generation failed,
                                    GetAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn getAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn
                                            = (GetAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn) object;
                                    showGetAllStockItemByCustomerErrorDialog(getAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn);

                                } else if (object instanceof List) {
                                    
                                    List<GetAllStockItemByCustomerResponseData> getAllStockItemByCustomerResponseDataList
                                            = (List<GetAllStockItemByCustomerResponseData>) object;
                                    //remove loading view
                                    articleDetailsList.remove(articleDetailsList.size() - 1);
                                    List<ArticleDetails> result = new ArrayList<>();
                                    result = homeActivityViewModel.getArticles(getAllStockItemByCustomerResponseDataList);
                                    homeActivityViewModel.insertAllStockItemByCustomer(context,filterTypeId
                                            , getAllStockItemByCustomerResponseDataList, null);
                                    if (result.size() > 0) {
                                        //add loaded data
                                        articleDetailsList.addAll(result);
                                    } else {//result size 0 means there is no more data available at server
                                        articleRecyclerViewAdapter.setMoreDataAvailable(false);
                                        //telling articleRecyclerViewAdapter to stop calling load more as no more server data available
                                        //Toast.makeText(context, "No More Data Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                    articleRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataChanged();
                                    //should call the custom method articleRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataChanged here to get the correct loading status

                                } else {
                                    MDToast.makeText(context, FinalVariables.ToastMessages.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG
                                            , MDToast.LENGTH_SHORT, MDToast.TYPE_WARNING).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                MDToast.makeText(context, FinalVariables.ToastMessages.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG
                                        , MDToast.LENGTH_SHORT, MDToast.TYPE_WARNING).show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                       
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

```
 private void load(String filterText, Integer categoryId, int offset, int numberOfRows) {

       
        Integer storeId = FileUtils.getPreferenceInt(context
                , Preferences.CUSTOMER_PREFERENCE, TagNames.STORE_ID);
        Integer distributionChannelId = FileUtils.getPreferenceInt(context
                , Preferences.CUSTOMER_PREFERENCE, TagNames.DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL_ID);
    
        homeActivityViewModel.getAllStockItemByCustomer(
                DeviceUtils.getCredential(context, ServiceNames.GET_ALL_STOCK_ITEM_BY_CUSTOMER)
                , storeId, distributionChannelId, filterTypeId, filterText, categoryId, offset, numberOfRows
                , new ApiCallbackListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object object) {
                     
                       
                        try {
                            if (object != null) {

                                if (object instanceof GetAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn) {
                                    
                                    GetAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn getAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn
                                            = (GetAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn) object;
                                    showGetAllStockItemByCustomerErrorDialog(getAllStockItemByCustomerStatusReturn);

                                } else if (object instanceof List) {
                                   
                                    List<GetAllStockItemByCustomerResponseData> getAllStockItemByCustomerResponseDataList
                                            = (List<GetAllStockItemByCustomerResponseData>) object;

                                 
                                    if (!getAllStockItemByCustomerResponseDataList.isEmpty()) {
                                        if (offset == 0 && getAllStockItemByCustomerResponseDataList.get(0)
                                                .getCategoryID() == StatusCodes.INVALID_CODE
                                                && filterTypeId == FilterTypes.SUGGESTED) {

                                            //shows all article from store (filter type 0) if no article is mapped in suggested.
                                            filterTypeId = FilterTypes.ALL;
                                            load(filterText, categoryId, offset, numberOfRows);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    articleDetailsList.addAll(homeActivityViewModel.getArticles(getAllStockItemByCustomerResponseDataList));
                                    homeActivityViewModel.insertAllStockItemByCustomer(context,filterTypeId
                                            , getAllStockItemByCustomerResponseDataList, null);
                                  
                                    articleRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataChanged();

                                } else {
                                    
                                }
                            } else {
                               
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: What happens is that you need to create a condition that restores the view to an original state. Remember that RecyclerView uses dirty views to form new views, so "Recycle". Then, in the onBindViewHolder, whenever you have an if, you must put an else condition, which cleans the state of that view. For example, let's say you want to paint a red button if a condition x and the original color of the view is blue. If you never put an else condition to paint the blue button again, you will surely use a red button to create a new view, but since there is no condition that restores the view to blue.

Comment: Your solution is an else condition for this: `if(getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_TYPE ITEM)` // Populate view ok , but, what should be happen if not? Do you need to clean the ImageViews? change the color of a view? Or just clean the information?